# C++ use struct as some type

Tags: c++, struct

Suppose I have this struct:

```
struct shape{
    int type;
    shape(){}
    shape(int _type){type = _type;}
};
```

Is it possible to use shape *as an int* directly? In this case, shape would assume the value of its type. For example:

```
shape s(2);
if     (s == 1) cout<<"this shape is a circle"<<endl;
else if(s == 2) cout<<"this shape is a triangle"<<endl;
else if(s == 3) cout<<"this shape is a rectangle"<<endl;
//...
```

In general, is it possible to use an struct so that it will assume a chosen value of one of its attributes? In shape's case, it was an int, but it could be a string or any other type.

---

EDIT: I tried the code suggested by @Jarod42 using string as type:

```
struct shape{
    string type;
    shape(){}
    shape(string _type){type = _type;}
    operator string() const {return type;}
};
```

And when I write

```
shape s1("circle");
string s2 = "circle";
if(s1 == s2){ ...
```

it says *error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'shape' and 'std::string)*, although with int as type, it works fine.

Comment: Just as a FYI, going down that path if fairly dangerous and often ill advised. You are often implicitely buying in to a bunch of APIs your class is not designed for. This only makes sense when you have a clear is-a relationship (which your shape class definitely does not have with `int`. What would `s+3` mean? it's important because it doesn't cause a compilation error anymore.)

Comment: `cout << "this shape is a " << (s == 1 ? "circle" : s == 2 ? "triangle" : s == 3 ? "rectangle" : "(unknown shape)") << "\n";` Or just use a `switch` statement. ;)

Comment: @Frank that's why you can make the conversion `explicit`, but of course it also might make more sense for a more highly developed `shape` API to have stream operators, comparison operators, etc. that let the final user of the class access a shape in the relevant ways without exposing implementation details. Of course you know that already.

Comment: int is a primitive datatype but strings are not. You need to overload the == operator for the comparison to work in your if condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might add `operator int`:

```
struct shape{
    int type;
    shape(){}
    shape(int _type) : type(_type) {}

    operator int() const { return type; }
};
```

Comment: would this work with any type? for example, would `operator string() const ...` or even if I have my own struct s, would `operator s() const ...` be corrrect?

Comment: Yes, you can define a conversion operator in `shape` to "convert" instances of it into any other type you want.

Comment: Yes, you might even return reference.

Comment: I tried using string as type and it gave me *no match for operator== between shape and string*.

Comment: It is because `std::string` is template as `operator ==`, so no `operator ==` match argument. you might convert explicitly to string in that case:
`std::string(s) == "circle"`

Answer (score 2):

In general you can use `operator T` where `T` is the type you want to cast to. If you want to force the use of `static_cast<T>(my_shape)`, then you can add the keyword `explicit` in front:

```
struct shape
{
    int type;

    shape() = default;
    shape(int _type) : type{ _type } {}

    operator int() const { return type; }
    explicit operator float() const { return type; }

    operator std::string() const
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case 1:
                return "circle";
            case 2:
                return "triangle";
            case 3:
                return "rectangle";
            default:
                break;
        }
        return "(unknown shape)";
    }
};
```

This will work with built-in types (`int`, `float`, `double`), standard types (`std::string`, `std::complex`), custom struct/class types, or even a pointer or a reference (if you have a static array of values, for example). You may want to consider whether you *need* these conversion operators (encapsulation is a whole other discussion), but this is conceptually how you would do it.

In this example, you may also want to introduce an `enum` for storing your type values:

```
struct shape
{
    enum type_t
    {
        circle = 1,
        triangle,
        rectangle
    };

    type_t type;

    operator std::string() const
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case circle:
                return "circle";
            case triangle:
                return "triangle";
            case rectangle:
                return "rectangle";
            default:
                break;
        }
        return "(unknown shape)";
    }

    shape(type_t _type) : type{ _type } {}

    // rest of class as before
};
```

Comment: How would I compare a shape s with a string? When I try `s == "circle"`, it says there is no operator == between shape and string.

Comment: You can implement it as a member function `bool operator==(std::string s) const` as part of the struct definition. Inside that function you could use a `switch` against `type` (like above), then for each case test the string's value: `case circle:  return s == "circle";`

Answer (score 1):

While using a cast operator is one way to do it, as shown by @Jarod42, I suggest making the operation a bit more explicit.

1. Add a function to get the type.
2. Use the function call and the returned value in the `if-else` statements.

---

```
struct shape{
    int type;
    shape(){}
    shape(int _type){type = _type;}
    int getType() const { return type;}
};
```

and then

```
shape s(2);
int type = s.getType();
if     (type == 1) cout<<"this shape is a circle"<<endl;
else if(type == 2) cout<<"this shape is a triangle"<<endl;
else if(type == 3) cout<<"this shape is a rectangle"<<endl;
```

Comment: I'm afraid to say this is not what I'm looking for, I want to explicitly use the struct as the type of one of its attributes (be it int, string or anything else)

Comment: @Daniel, that's your choice, of course. In my experience, I have found that such implicit conversions lead to buggy and hard to understand code.

Comment: I'm asking just because it got me curious, it is not a practice that I'll add in a serious code

Comment: @RSahu conversion operators don't have to be implicit. You can add the `explicit` specifier before the operator and then it can only be used via `static_cast`.

Comment: @RSahu it's also considered [bad practice in programming to repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), so the OP's `cout` calls "*should*" be simplified.

Comment: @monkey0506, I agree. I didn't want to the focus away from the implicit cast operator.

Comment: @RSahu I figured you knew, but that's why I omitted the `cout` example code from my own answer, because it wasn't really relevant to the answer. Your implementation is a bit different though, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do in the end is compare the shape by string, then there is a simpler and **much safer** solution:

```
struct shape{
    std::string type;

    shape() {}

    bool operator==(std::string const& rhs) const {
      return type == rhs;
    }
};

// and if you want to be able to do string == shape.
bool operator==(std::string const& lhs, shape const& rhs) {
  return rhs == lhs;
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 Well, you don't HAVE to in order to meet the asker's goal,  but it's definitely a good idea in general, I've added it to the answer.